# PSSM Matrix in PSI-BLAST

Tags: sequence-alignment, proteins, blast, pssm, psi-blast

After running PSI-BLAST one obtains a profile matrix with this header:

```
 A   R   N   D   C   Q   E   G   H   I   L   K   M   F   P   S   T   W   Y   V
```

How does PSI-BLAST handles X and B "residues" in the fasta file then?

---

- X residue being an amino acid that can't be assigned due to the presence of nucleotide ambiguities which result in the codon representing more than one amino acid.
- B (beta) residues, with the exception of B-alanine are singly generated *in vitro* and being explored for their putative antibacterial properties.
- PSSM is the position specific score matrix

Comment: It's a blast thing in general. Degenerate bases are ignored in DNA queries. Pyr, asx & glx in protein also. I don't think they count as a gap, but instead these IUPAC letters and any random letter (=non-space/non-punctuation) character (even Unicode IIRC) become a masked character —they will be in grey if so: it would straightforward to test by simply doing a pairwise alignments with one sequence with asparax (B) and glutamax (Z) replacing the respective amide/acids. There should be written somewhere how masked characters behave during scoring.